# How to make a table cell clickable with an Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table cell which I want the user to be able to click to go to an AJAX action, so I have something like

```
<td class="code-cell">
@Ajax.ActionLink(Model.Code, "Edit", "MyController",
                    new { id = Model.Id }, 
                    new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "GET", 
                            UpdateTargetId = "edit", 
                            InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace
                        }, new { @class = "code-link" })
</td>
```

which puts a link in the table cell.

But I want the user to be able to click on the cell rather than having to click the link.

Using jquery I can wire up an event handler to the click on the td (via a class) and then find the child link and click it. But I'm having trouble with understanding event propagation, etc.

I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".code-cell").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $("a", this).triggerHandler("click");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Even though I've tried the calls to e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() (and various combinations!) I can't seem to get this to work.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
return false;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Try $(this).find('a').click()

Answer (score 0):

Another way to tackle this without javascript could be to set the css display to block for the action link.

Doing this will mean the action link takes up 100% width within the table cell therefore giving a bigger area for the user to click.

Something to note - if your *td* has padding then theres going to be a gap where the padding exists i.e between the *td* and *a* elements.

So your CSS could look like this

```
td .a 
{
    display: block;
}
```

or since you have a class

```
a.code-link
{
    display: block;
}
```